# How to get full string value from database?

Tags: php, forms

What i have is form. Inside form there is list of checkboxes, data for this checkboxes is taken from database. Here is some data from `theme_name` column:

```
| theme_name |
+------------+
|  BGD LYT   |
|  BGD COL   |
|  BLD RIG   |
|  BLD SWB   |
|  CGI ANM   |
|  CGI MOD   |
```

I am able to get this data and print it for user :

```
<form method="post" action="createProject2.php">
<?php 
    $result = getProcessID();
?>
<div class="scrollable" id="checkboxes">    
<?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row[0] = cleanOutputData($row[0]);                             
?>      
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value=<?php echo $row[0]?> /><?php echo $row[0] ?>

<?php
   }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
 ?>         
 </div>

<input type = "submit" name ="submit" class="button" onclick="userSubmitted = true;" value = "Continue"/>

</form>
```

But what im getting on page `createProject2.php` is:

```
<?php
$proc = isset($_POST['process'])?$_POST['process']:''; 
$len = count($proc); // getting length of ur array that u need to condition ur loop 
?>

<?php
    //an array of inputs
    for($y=0;$y<$len;$y++)
    {
?>
    <input type='text' name='holdprocess[]' value="<?php echo $proc[$y]?>">     
<?php
    }
?>
```

And instead of for example `BGD LYT` i get just `BGD`. And same for all values. How i can get full value of the string? Thank you

Comment: inside <input> tag, enclose the data of "value" attribute within quotes..

Comment: focus here: `FOREIGN KEY (proc_leader) REFERENCES user(username)` ... if you need help ping me in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not use double quotes to enclose the input value.

I.e.

```
value=ABC DEF
```

html will treat value to be ABC and DEF as another attribute.

Use double quotes instead.

```
value="ABC DEF"
```

Comment: OP should ideally use `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($whatever) ?>"`

Comment: We all have been there.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add single quotes.

For the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="process[]" id=<?php echo $row[0] ?>  value=<?php echo "'".$row[0]."'" ?> /><?php echo $row[0] ?>
```

php page:

```
<input type='text' name='holdprocess[]' value="<?php echo "'".$proc[$y]."'" ?>">
```